# how to clear/zero a variable in nasm assembler (x64)?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm trying to build an assmebler program with a little loop and string comparing. However, when I jump to the main funtion again (in `unknown`), `input` is not empty and still filled with the entered string. But the user should be able to enter another string. How to empty this `input` variable/label?

My code:

```
section .data:
  input: resb 16
  welcome_msg: db "Welcome to this a bit more complex assembler program!", 0x0a
  welcome_msg_len equ $-welcome_msg
  msg_1: db "Type exit to exit the program", 0x0a
  msg_1_len equ $-msg_1
  msg_2: db "Unknown command!", 0x0a
  msg_2_len equ $-msg_1
  exit: db "exit", 0x0a

section .text
global _start
_start:
  jmp main

unknown:
  jmp main

exit_func:
  ; exit the programm
  mov rax, 60
  mov rdi, 0
  syscall

main:
  ; print the welcome_msg
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, welcome_msg
  mov rdx, welcome_msg_len
  syscall
  ; print the msg_1
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, msg_1
  mov rdx, msg_1_len
  syscall
  ; wait for user input
  mov rax, 0
  mov rdi, 0
  mov rsi, input
  mov rdx, 16
  syscall
  ; compare the input
  mov rdi, exit
  mov rsi, input
  mov rcx, 4
  repe cmpsb
  je exit_func
  ; print the msg_1
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, msg_2
  mov rdx, msg_2_len
  syscall
  jmp unknown
```

Comment: Three `call`s and no `ret`s?  Are you sure that's the control flow you want?

Comment: @Erik Eidt yes.

Comment: Why use `call` if you're not going to `ret` anywhere?

Comment: @Erik Eidt I think thats not my main problem here.

Comment: Did you want to actually allocate some space for `input`? As written, there's nothing between `input` and `welcome_msg`, so the two labels have the same address and when you read into `input`, it overwrites your welcome message.

Comment: Possibly you meant that line to be something like `input: resb 16`

Comment: Ok, but how to clear ```input``` ?

Comment: There's no need to clear it before inputting.  But if you must, then write zeros there.

Comment: Using `call` instead of `jmp` pushes a return address.  That will eventually overflow the stack and segfault if your loop runs long enough.  That's something you should fix regardless of other bugs.

Comment: Ok, I edited the post. Can someone answer my question please?